# Converting citygml to KML?

Tags: java, software-recommendations, rendering, citygml

I am trying to render citygml files. I am using NWW for rendering purpose. I have used citygml4j library to extract the GroundSurface, roof, and walls geometry, and was able to render them. But due to the huge data specification of citygml, I am having troubles with more complex files. So I am looking for some java library that can convert citygml file to kml data format, which can be easy visualized in World wind. I have seen the 3dcitydb and found that pretty cool, but couldn't find any set of apis that can be used for my purpose.(haven't completely explored that).

Does there exist some java library that can fulfill my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the most important fact! CityGML is not a rendering format. It is designed to exchange information which explains its complexity.

If you need KML you can use the already mentioned 3DCityDB. It has an export plugin to KML and COLLADA. At the moment many developers are going for COLLADA which you can convert into glTF and throw to Cesium.

You can also work directly with the PostGIS database. It has got functions like AsKML or AsX3D you might use.

Comment: Thanks @Felix for the answer, but I am making a simple application on world wind that can read citygml, extract geometries from it and then render it on World Wind. So far I was able to extract soild, Ground, roof, walls and was able to render them. I was asking about kml, because of the easiness of kml visualization on WW. I will look into the kml exporter plugin. :)